# Getting response after redirect in the ajax call

Tags: ajax, spring-mvc

I have a ajax call to an external url which returns a json object. The external service needs a key which I dont want to leave as text in the javascript. So I decided to route the ajax call  to spring controller where I can append the keys to the url(hiding the keys from the external world) before doing the redirect.
But after doing the redirect I am not able to get the response(in my case json objects) in the ajax call.

My ajax call

```
http_request.open("GET", "search.html", true);
if (http_request.readyState == done && http_request.status == ok) {
...
}
```

My controller

```
@RequestMapping("/search")
public class SearchController  {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET) 
    public String search(){
        return "redirect:http://www.xyz.com?key=myKey";
    }
}
```

Comment: Is http://www.xyz.com your domain or a different domain? (You know that you can't request resources from a different domain, right?)

Comment: Its a different external domain.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript

Comment: I think the request to the controller would work, but the redirect to a different site might cause unexpected results.  You'd have to like use something like HttpClient through Apache to make the request and parse the results.